# Custom wizard page - Inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I want to change my Inno Setup first page so that i can use a custom image that i did in Photoshop to fit all of the wizard window. I just want the image (no buttons or toolbars). The tricky part is that i did 3 buttons for that image (Install, Read Manual, Faq).

Is this possible with Inno-Setup, can i trigger a event in the area of the image button? thank you!

Comment: Would you mind if there wouldn't be highlighting of those "buttons" when hovering ?

Comment: No mind at all! I am using issi plugin to extend the background image to fit the wizard width. So far so good. The trouble is how to get the buttons in the image working.

Comment: Sorry to bring up this old thread, but: InnoSetup doesn't have a concept of clickable image maps. You can not have click events for just some region, you really need a button. What you could try is place buttons in the respective location.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten! I did it in a different way, but is good to know.